# How can I have CC.NET build to a specific hg (Mercurial) tag?

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use tags in cc.net to control release build. When I have the build machine build for development, I have it tag with a keyword - 'release'. Now I would like to have the production project build using the same repository tag to build.

Since the tag 'release' would resolve to the most recent version, it should build the repository at exactly the same place as the development build.

Here is what I am using for the development project:

```
<sourcecontrol type="hg">
    <repo>//pdesql/SoftwareDevelopment/Repository/PBJ</repo>
    <workingDirectory>C:\build\pbj-dev-deploy</workingDirectory>
    <tagCommitMessage>release</tagCommitMessage>
    <tagOnSuccess>true</tagOnSuccess>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: You're not actually using the `<tagNameFormat>ccnet_build_{0}</tagNameFormat>` setting, so what is being committed for the tag name?  I didn't think you could have duplicate tags and therefore wouldn't be able to do this more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a fragment to the end of the repo address:

```
//pdesql/SoftwareDevelopment/Repository/PBJ#TagName
```

You can read more about this by typing `hg help urls`

**Note**: his appears to be broken in the latest version. For now, I've had to downgrade Mercurial on our buildserver to 1.7.3 (one I know it works in). I've filed a bug [here](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2997).

I also posted a little more [on my blog](http://blog.dantup.com/2011/09/automating-deployment-building-a-specific-mercurial-tag-on-cruisecontrol-net) about how I'm using this :-)

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work. Didn't occur to me that it might be broken.

Comment: I rolled back to 1.7.3 (known to work), but I think it was broken in 1.9, so 1.8.x probably works too. A fix has been committed, however when I tested it it didn't seem to work correctly - need to try again, as the author believes the fix should work.